# What does Vincent inject himself in Titane?

Tags: plot-explanation, titane

In the movie [*Titane*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titane) (2021), by Julia Ducournau, the character named Vincent injects himself substances throughout the film.

In the first scene where it happens, we cannot see what he is filling his syringe with, but I think that the spectator is assumed to guess it. What is it?

To be more precise, after the first time, we indeed see him put the syringe into a tiny bottle of what we assume to be steroids. However, the way the first scene is shot (we see him naked, from the back) made me think that maybe he was reinjecting himself something from his own body (it may even come from his testicles)...

So, is he always injecting himself steroids that he takes from the tiny bottle? Could it be that the first scene is shot this way on purpose so the spectator may wonder about what is really happening?

Answer (score 2):

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titane#Plot):

> Vincent tries to preserve his strength by **injecting steroids** into his aging body, but he finds that he seems to be building an immunity to them.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get the notification for your answer and did not come back to look. I will edit my question accordingly, but... the second time and the following, we see him putting the syringe in a little bottle of what we expect to be steroids. However, the first time, we see him naked, from the back, and the syringe is at approximately the same height as his... testicles. So, I wondered if it happens that some people reinject themselves something that they take out of their own testicles.

Answer (score 1):

### Steroids

> At the director’s insistence, Lindon also took up bodybuilding for the
> year preceding the shoot in the autumn of 2020 to bulk up his
> physique. **“In the screenplay, his character is injecting steroids,”
> explains Ducournau.** Muscle mass was necessary for the audience to
> understand exactly what was being injected, “other­wise it might look
> like the character had diabetes or some other issue. He did an amazing
> job and actually enjoyed it, but this is something Vincent and I have
> in common — our belief that the first way to understand the character
> is through the body.”
>
> <sub><sup>[‘Titane’ director Julia Ducournau talks nudity, car culture and subverting masculinity](https://www.screendaily.com/features/titane-director-julia-ducournau-talks-nudity-car-culture-and-subverting-masculinity/5165752.article)</sup></sub>